# Call Authorized Api Gateway endpoint from AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to define a Lambda function that call authenticated endpoint of API Gateway (`authorizationType: AWS_IAM` ).
I've already create the policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke",
                "execute-api:InvalidateCache"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:<account_id>:*/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And attach the policy to lambda.
But the response from endpoint called is already 403 (forbidden).
I think i have to add some authorization headers to request.
This is the example lambda code (ruby):

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'
API_GATEWAY_URL = ENV["API_GATEWAY_URL"]
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  env = event&.dig("env")
  endpoint = event&.dig("enpoint")
  complete_url = "https://#{env}.#{API_GATEWAY_URL}/#{endpoint}"
  response = HTTParty.get(complete_url)
  p response.code
  p response.body
end
```

Does anyone know how i can proceed ? thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if the API gateway is configured with auth key?

if yes, your application should pass it through the header with the key `x-api-key`

API Endpoint with Auth API-Key looks like this:

[image]